# Как правильно прописывать ключевые слова

Tags: html

Как правильно прописывать ключевые слова

```
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
```

кокой длины могут быть ключевые слова, как их лучше разделять, могут ли быть ключами выражения?

Comment: Никак. Большинство поисковиков их давно игнорируют.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ключевые слова задаются тегом , атрибут name имеет значение keywords. Ключевые слова перечисляются в атрибуте content через запятую:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="важные, ключевые, слова">
```

Раньше этот тег был важен для SEO, но сегодня его положение неоднозначно, Яндекс и Гугл говорят, что "учитывают" ключевые слова, но не в качестве основы для индексации, точной информации поисковики не дают!)

Comment: Правильно пишешь. Данный тег советуют последнее время вообще не использовать или писать 1-2 слова которые на 100% описывают о чем страница.

Comment: Одним из самых главных параметров для поисков являются атрибуты alt и его содержание в img. Ну и, конечно же, schema.